# Split reads to a different connection string

Tags: php, database

Anyone know if there's a way to catch the database connection object, and change the connection string under it? Basically I want to redirect the commands that don't have the words INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE or EXEC to another server name which would be a load balancer of sorts.

I browsed the docs, but couldn't find anything that looked right. That said, I'm not a developer by trade.

Comment: I think you want use master slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Wordpress [HyperDB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/) plugin.

Comment: Are their any better options? This apparently hasn't been updated in 2 years now.